# Using iCloud for a custom sync protocol

Tags: ios, icloud

I'd like to use iCloud to sync between instances of my app running on different devices (e.g. my users have data on their iPad, iPod Touch and iPhone and they want them all to stay in sync).

Are there any good algorithms for this kind of sync (smart devices, "dumb" key-value only data store)?  It sounds like a sync system of this sort would resemble a distributed version control system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read the [iCloud developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW1) yet? iCloud pretty much handles the synchronization for you. What it doesn't do, however, is to handle merge conflicts. You'll need to provide code to handle such conflicts.

Comment: Merge conflicts are also handled very well now. :)